# How to implement a jquery .change code if selector is created dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website where the user can select a product of (html) list. This list is (must be) created dynamically by means of a javascript function(getOptionsForm()). When the user selects a product in the list, related productdetails must be shown in a box. Different details must be shown when the user selects another box, and this part is what I struggle with;

My problem is I struggle implementing the display of productdetail information in the box; somehow the jquery .change() does not work and I think I understand why, but I dont know how to solve it; how to apply the .change() function when its selector (class ordertype) is created dynamically?

Pls see the simplified example code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var getOptionsForm = function() {
        var form = $('<select class="ordertype"> <option value='1'> prod1 </option><option  value='2'> prod2 </option> </select>');
    }

    var form = getOptionsForm();

    $('#wrapper').append(form);

    $(".ordertype").focus(function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous1 = this.value; //old select value
    }).change(function() {
        $('#prod-details').html('show something');
        previous1 = this.value;
    }); 

}); //$(document).ready

<div id="wrapper"> </div>
<div id="prod-details"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with event delegation, you can delegate the event to parent of dynamically added element.

```
$('#wrapper').on('change', '.ordertype', function() {    
    $('#prod-details').html('show something');
    previous1 = this.value;
});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: A `.` is missing for the selector.

Comment: You are welcome, there was an extra ( before call back function, I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation, bind the selector to an element that does exist at DOM ready with `.on()`

```
$("#wrapper").on("change", ".ordertype", function() {
    //do your stuff!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 choices :

1. Event delegation (as said before by the other answers and which is nicer)
2. Adding the Event Listener at the element creation and after appending into the DOM

   ```
   var getOptionsForm = function() { 

       var form = $('<select class="ordertype"> <option value='1'> prod1 </option><option  value='2'> prod2 </option> </select>');
       $('#wrapper').append(form);

       $(".ordertype").focus(function () {
           // Store the current value on focus and on change
           previous1 = this.value; //old select value
       }).change(function() {
           $('#prod-details').html('show something');
           previous1 = this.value;
       });}
   }
   ```